# Does Rocket Bluezone has any session timeout to prevent working after certain time?

Tags: vba, bluezone

```
Sub Fullflow()
Dim WorkBookName As String
Dim Host
bookname = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
WorkBookName = "" & bookname & "\MasterSheetFetchJob.xlsm"
Set src = Workbooks.Open(WorkBookName, True, True)
iTotalRows = src.Worksheets("CardDetails").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
GetCardNumber
'If GetCardNumber Returns atleast one card then run the rest of the jobs.
If iTotalRows > 1 Then
    GenerateCVV
    GeneratePINBLOCK
    GenerateATC
    GetNameAndCurrency
    updateTestData
    updateMaxAndMinAmountInTestDataSheet
    updatePinBlockCountInTestData
    updateChipFallbackinTestData
    updateAmountFieldForInsufficientFunds
    RestartLine
Else
    Set Host = CreateObject("BZWhll.WhllObj")
    Retval = Host.Connect("A")
    Host.WaitReady 10, 2000
    Host.Exit
End If
End Sub
```

I have written few independent function combining all in one flow..

`GetCardNumber` alone opens the Rocket Bluezone Mainframe **`TN3270`** Emulator.. I am not closing emaulator until it runs RestartLine..

Other than `GetCardNumber` every function has this function to connect mainframe emulator.

```
Set Host = CreateObject("BZWhll.WhllObj")
Retval = Host.Connect("A")
```

In my local, all functions working perfectly if i run Fullflow macro..

But in one of the others machine, it runs until 15 mins (all the 15 mins it is doing job and it is not in inactivity state), after that it is not connecting to Mainframe using code but i am able to interact emualtor with Manually.. After 15 mins, the code is not running..  Is there any configuration settings or anything which prevents this to run..?

I am using Bluezone 7.1.8 and the other machine has 7.1.6.. Is this causing issue or any configuration?

Comment: Are you observing the computer when it stops running? Is this running on an unattended machine? It might be the host computer is going to sleep, or, it could be the `keep-alive` setting is not configured to your liking. Have a look here: https://www3.rocketsoftware.com/bluezone/help/v37/sss/Configuration/Configuring_a_Connection.htm

Comment: When i check both machines, keep-alive: None under connections properties.

Comment: Try setting the keep alive to something like 10 min. See if it makes a difference.

Comment: after setting up, it got disconnected after 10mins

Comment: Try lowering to 1 min as a test.